# iOS: Keeping views proportionally sized to each other using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have an UIImageView called 'logo' inside a UIView called 'container'. The logo is centred inside the container both horizontally and vertically.

Depending upon the screen size the app is running in the height of the container changes based on constraints. I would like the size of the logo to change proportionally to the height of the container as on the 3.5 inch display it is too large at its normal size.

Can anyone tell me what constraint I should be placing on the logo and/or container to change the logo's size? I'd love to be able to do this without resorting to code as I believe I should be able to set this up in IB. Many thanks.

Comment: what constraints you have given to container ? , also you have provided different logo image for 3.5 inch screen ?

Comment: There is just one logo image for all screen sizes. It centres itself on all resolutions. The container has constraints for pinning it to the sides, top and two for its height. One that sets its hight but has a low priority and another that has a higher priority and makes sure it doesn't go over a certain height, a max height constraint. These are working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can press control and at the same time drag the image "logo" to it`s superview container and chose equal height . click the logo and chose the size inspector on the right, you will find a lot constraints then chose Equal Height to.
2. Double click Equal Height and you will see the detail constraints, the first item: the logo image,relation :equal ,second item:you should chose the super view,Multiplier set 1. it means firstItem.propery = secondItem.propery relation Multiplier + constant;

I hope it can help you ,if you want to know more ,you can read some thing about AutoLayout in WWDC 2014

Comment: thanks Andrew, I've been missing around with that trying out all the different combinations but it is not working, either the container changes size or nothing seems to happen :(

Comment: Actually I had to kill my simulator and restart with a clean build and that seemed to get things working as expected. Thanks Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

In your xib file, first check the imageview logo is in subview of your container view, then select your imageview and the container view using command key. Once both are selected, go to editor menu and select Heights equally and width equally one by one under pin option.
Then select the constraint you just added, go to attributed inspector, change the multiplier in the ratio you want, like 2:3 (it means the height of your logo will be in the ratio of 2:3 of your container view's height  if your first item is logo or else set it to 3:2).